# Facebook permission requests - when to ask?

Tags: forms

I am working on a 'fun' Facebook app that asks ten questions and presents you with a 'fun' result. We need to ask permission to access some of the users data, this consists of their 'Basic Information' and posts to their Wall. In your opinion, is it best to ask for these permissions up-front or wait until they have finished the quiz, just before the resolution? So it would be 'If you want to see the finished result, grant you permission' basically.

The thing is, if they decline the permissions they do not get the resolution at the end, the app would bomb out and drop them back at the beginning.

Comment: Why is "fun" between quotation marks? Is it not really fun?

Comment: It is supposed to be fun yes but my heart says it is not all that great to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you are saying, getting them to do the quiz and then not giving the answers until they grant their permission is going to feel they've been tricked.

Having worked on a number of Facebook apps, it's pretty standard to ask permission to access user data upfront and the majority of users will be familiar with the question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it does help as it concurs with what I recommended and also best practice form design really.

Answer (score 2):

Since a user does not know at the beginning what is actually going to be posted to their wall, they might be less inclined to agree up front. Can you not show the result and at the same time ask if they would like to also post it to their wall?